# JQuery select row in table, change css in div in this row

Tags: jquery, css, select, row

I have a table with some rows and columns, some cells have div element inside. I would like to change div class in a row which I clicked. Also, I need to remove this class when I click on the row again or when I click on another row. I try to create `jQuery` script, but I'm not successful. Once I change every div in the table, in second try its do nothing. My last "wrong" version of jquery is:

```
jQuery(document).on("click", "tr.line > td", function () {
    var $this = jQuery(this);


    if jQuery.find("div").hasClass('zna')) {
        jQuery.find("div").removeClass("zna");
    }
    else {

        jQuery.find("div").removeClass("zna");
        jQuery.find("div").addClass("zna");
    }
});
```

can anybody help?

Comment: `if jQuery.find("div").hasClass('zna'))` is a syntax error. Why are you removing a class, then adding it back again in the `else` case? `jQuery.find` is an alias for `Sizzle`. Are you sure you don’t want to use the `find` method on a jQuery object that takes the _context_ from it, like `jQuery(someSelector).find`? Do you really want to target the _same_ `<div>`? `jQuery.find` returns an `Array` which doesn’t have any of the class methods you’re using. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what exactly you mean but this maybe can help you

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("section").on("click", function() { //example click handler
    if ( $(this).find("div").hasClass("zna") ) {
      $("div").toggleClass("zna");
    } else {
      $("div").toggleClass("zna");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
section {
  width:75px
  height:50px;
  padding:5px;
  border:1px solid;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.test {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:green;
  display:inline-block;
}

.test.zna {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>click me
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test zna"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: yes, this is what I need, but I need it to apply on one row in table ( on childs in row) Thx :-)

Answer (score -1):

I think we might need to see your markup from your table to be sure, but at first glance your if evaluation is missing an open parenthesis... There could also be other issues but this is just my first thoughts. The if statement needs open and closed () for the evaluation parameters.

```
jQuery(document).on("click", "tr.line > td", function () {
var $this = jQuery(this);


if (jQuery.find("div").hasClass('zna')) {
    jQuery.find("div").removeClass("zna");
}
else {

    jQuery.find("div").removeClass("zna");
    jQuery.find("div").addClass("zna");
}
```